# CORBA location forward and Network Address Translation

Tags: java, corba, nat

I'm using CORBA to access a Java server from a Java client. (Currently I'm using the OpenORB implementation.) Everything works fine so far.

When I want to change my network setup and have the server behind a router that does **Network Address Translation**, I get a connection problem. Here is what happens:

```
Client -> Server: GPIO 1.0 Request is_a
Server -> Client: GPIO 1.0 Reply: Location Forward: 192.168.1.101:9999
```

Because the server does not know its external IP address in the new setup, the location forward fails.

Is there a way to disable this **Location Forward** "feature"?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I found that this happens only when using the Corbaloc Name service, not when connecting with an IOR directly

Comment: The server doesn't need to know it's external address to send data to client. It needs to know the clients external/public address to send the data to client.

Comment: Some ORBs do have a flag to overrule the ip address that is put into the IOR, for example TAO has one, check the OpenORB documentation if they support such a flag

Comment: @Tahlil: That's what you'd normally think. But the server re-announces the IP it is available on in a location forward. Look at the extract of the protocoll I gave, I obtained it with a packet sniffer

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen: That's true. The OpenORB implementation does have that flag, but that doesn't help, because the server doesn't know its external IP (its dynamic), so it cannot set this flag :-(

Comment: Could it be that you are using the IORTable support, that triggers a location forward in the server.

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen No, I'm not using IORTable support. I think it is the default behavior. Maybe its related to a GPIO protocol version handling. In a working setup it continues like this (note the version 1.2): `Client -> Server: GPIO 1.2 Request is_a;  Server -> Client: GPIO 1.2 Reply: No Exception`

Comment: Just to follow up on @JohnnyWillemsen's comment: what works for me is something like `-ORBListenEndpoints iiop://:1234/hostname_in_ior=my-corba-server.example.com`. This way the server doesn't need to know the external IP address (but needs to know a name for it obviously).